# Oracle For Exchange Defaults

Tags: oracles

Simple question, is there a trustworthy oracle that can tell me whether an exchange (e.g. binance) defaulted, froze withdrawals, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Simple question, is there a trustworthy oracle that can tell me whether an exchange (e.g. binance) defaulted, froze withdrawals, etc.

There is no such oracle.

However you can probably open your own prediction market bet with a certain timeframe and use the prediction market dispute resolution to settle the fact.